# Authorization hangs on App authorization page

Tags: android, authentication, dialog, facebook-android-sdk, freeze

In Hackbook Android sample and any other Facebook SDK 3.0.1 samples i getting trouble to login.

I go through facebook login dialog and after successful authentication then app authorization dialog appears: "Hackbook would like to access your public profile, friend list and photos" with Cancel and OK buttons. Click on any these buttons has no effect. Only way to return to app is press hardware back button.

Samples works well some days ago. I've tried to register own app id and replace it in samples, generate hashes for android native application, change app name and package, nothing helps.

Please point what's going wrong.

Comment: However this bug not reproduced on other device. For other functionality devices works same. Facebook app works well on both devices. I'm doubt..

Comment: Better if you add some logcat snapshots. If both Cancel and OK buttons gave no results there must be some errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue which might be afflicting you as well. I had the same behavior you are seeing and I figured out it was due to having the "Don't keep activities" developer option turned on. If that option is on and you have not yet logged into the native Facebook app then you will go into an infinite loop on login. It is a bug with the Facebook SDK for Android.

Here is the bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/269489836511974.